# automate email validation using telnet

Tags: shell, unix, smtp, telnet

I'm trying to use following script to validate if an email address exists:

```
telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
helo example.com
mail from: <me@example.com>
rcpt to: <somenonexistinguser@gmail.com>
```

How could I automate this process since I have a list of emails addresses need be validated? I need determine it's valid or not based on return value (550 or 220) and then quit then move to next email address.

Answer (score 1):

SMTP-quirks like [greet-delays](http://www.postfix.org/POSTSCREEN_README.html#pregreet) and [multi-line smtp replies](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.2.1) are difficult to automate using telnet. I suggest you use a RFC-compliant SMTP library in the programming language of your choice, for example python's [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html). Remember that there are more return codes than 550 and 220 which you need to handle as well. For example 4xx codes happen quite often (greylisting, overquota, ...)

Note however, that this is not a reliable way to validate an email address. Many servers accept any address in their hosted domains during the SMTP stage and bounce them afterwards.
Also, these kinds of SMTP-Probes are considered abusive by some postmasters and can lead to blacklistings.

Answer (score 0):

depending on your use case you can do it in a number of ways.

Some problems you may encounter trying to do it with telnet are blocked IPs and different response codes depending on the email domain.

### csv from shell

If you have a csv file you could automate processing the file using a service like [Real Email](https://isitarealemail.com/).
eg

```sh
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo $line, `curl "https://isitarealemail.com/api/email/validate?email=$line" -H 'Authorization: bearer xxx' | jq .status`;
done < emails-input.csv > emails-output.csv
```

#### python function

If you have an automated workflow you could call the API programatically, eg with a  python function that validates like this.

```
import requests

email_address = "foo@bar.com"
response = requests.get("https://isitarealemail.com/api/email/validate",
    params = {'email': email_address})

response.json()['status']
u'valid'
```

[bulk validations with real email](https://docs.isitarealemail.com/bulk-csv-file-email-validation)

[automated validations using python and real email](https://docs.isitarealemail.com/how-to-validate-email-addresses-in-python)